# cotentful api map content types to components in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, contentful

I am using contentful api to get content for a news-article and the body contains diffrent fields like question and answer. I use the api to get the content as json and i get the body as an array of objects.

```
      "body": [
      {
        "question": "what's up?"
      },
      {
        "answer": "good good"
      }
    ],
```

I'm wondering if could map each field in the body array to different react component and pass the right props to that component?

```
<div {...other}>
   {items.map((item, key) => (
     React.cloneElement(children, {
       key,
       ...item,
     })
   ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried so far? Check out https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html for more info on components and properties.

Comment: i have tried mapping then over the problem is i don't know what the article-body will contain. body array is like a array of different elements so question would a p with certain styling and the same would be for answer

Comment: I suggest you add some code to your question to make it more clear what you have tried and what you are trying to achieve. I don't quite understand what you mean by "An array of different elements" and "p with certain styling".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is mapping basically each `type` of field in your contentType like `Text` `LongText` etc ... to a react component.

If that's the case you could request first your contentType and go through its fields and based on the `type` property map it to your react component we use the same approach in our [discovery app](https://github.com/contentful/discovery-app-react).

This [snippet](https://github.com/contentful/discovery-app-react/blob/master/src/components/entries/Field.js) of code will give you a rough idea on how to achieve that.
BTW the app is created using react and redux, and it is compatible with any type of content created in [contentful](https://contentful.com).So you migh find more useful stuff there for creating your current project.

Best,

Khaled

Comment: Yes and i have a main contentType that have a field named body that is a reference to other contentTypes. Could i access those fields from the main contentType or do i have have to call every contentType in the body field?  @Khaled Garbaya

Comment: If you request all contentTypes using `client.getContentTypes()` and for every link you can get the linked ContentType fro you collection using the its `sys.id`. So you mapping could be recursive starting from the main contentType and going deep based on how many linked contenType you have.